# AZCopy Get list of failed transfer files

Tags: azcopy

When running azcopy it shows that "Transfer failed: 5" the output $Result does not tell which files failed.

```
$Result = & $azcopyLocation /Source:$TempDestination /Dest:$deploymentPath /destkey:$destinationKey /NC:30 /S /Y
```

Is there a way to find out which files failed to copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "/V:" and enter a directory and txt file name, like: 
/V:C:\AzCopy\Logs\Log.txt 
It creates a log file which says which fails were uploaded and which were not and any errors that might occur.