# AZCopy, see errors and failed transfer info

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azcopy

when using AZCopy to download files, how do I get information about what files failed to transfer, and what the error was? All I get is a message stating how many files failed.

```
sudo azcopy \
    --source <url> \
    --destination <path> \
    --source-key <key> \
    --include "<something>" \
    --recursive
```

I did see this post [AZCopy Get list of failed transfer files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510213/azcopy-get-list-of-failed-transfer-files), but the --V parameteter isn't recognized.

I also tried

--verbose < path> \

but it's not recognizing the path parameter, either with or without quotation marks.

Answer (score 2):

You should just check the status with [`azcopy jobs show`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy#view-and-resume-jobs):

```
azcopy jobs show <job-id> --with-status=Failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the `AzCopy V10` for my linux and window system. It will gives a log file with all the messages. You can download `AzCopy V10` from here: [Download AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10#download-azcopy).

For example, I download all files `tb5.text` from my Azure Blob storage in  linux, run the azcopy command, I can see all the message from the log file.
My Azcopy command:

```
./azcopy copy https://**.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/tb5.text /home/leon/azcopy_linux_amd64_10.1.2
```

[image]

You can open the log files and get all the info:
[image]

I also tried download the file this the error, AzCopy V10 will shows the error directly:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

i resolved a similar error by appending SAS token at the end of container url to where I want to copy my file and this change made me to successfully copy to my storage container.

> azcopy copy "source path" "container path?SAS TOKEN" --recursive